Create Customized tables
I was wondering if it is possible to create customized tables in LaTeX similar to the one shown in the picture below. I have searched extensively online, but I couldn't find any satisfactory solutions. I'm hoping you can assist me
That's my attempt
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\definecolor{rowcol}{rgb}{0.7, 0.7, 0.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
          colspec={Q[c,m,wd=3cm] *{4}{Q[c,m]}},
          cells={font=\large},
          cell{1}{1}={r=2}{},
          cell{1}{2}={c=3}{},
          row{7-8}={bg=rowcol},
          hline{1-Z}={1}{-}{leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
          hline{3}={2}{-}{leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
          vlines,
          vline{2}={2}{-}{},
      }
      & Countries \\
      & 1 & 2 & $\ldots$ & N \\
      Inputs & $Z_{11}$ & $Z_{12}$ & $\ldots$ & $Z_{1N}$ \\
      Inputs & $Z_{21}$ & $Z_{22}$ & $\ldots$ & $Z_{2N}$ \\
      Inputs & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
      Inputs & $Z_{N1}$ & $Z_{N2}$ & $\ldots$ & $Z_{NN}$ \\
      Value Added & VA$_1$ & VA$_2$ & $\ldots$ & VA$_4$ \\
      Total Output & $X_1$ & $X_2$ & $\ldots$ & $X_4$ \\
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}

Could you enhance the readability (e.g.The "Input" word should not repeat, and it appears that the $N$ column is detached) and ensure the table is not floating?

Have a look at the nicematrix package

Yes, you can. See, for example tabularray. For helping you we need a minimal example of what you tried. Please add it!

Do you literally want to insert \dots in some of the cells? Or should there be a fixed number of columns and/or rows? Please advise.

Yes, I want to insert $\dots$ in come cells. I'm gonna show you my attempt

Thank you. Can you please add a screenshot? I.e. I wonder about the colors you defined, and what their visual message is going to be.

About the colors, feel free to add any grey color that you think fits more. The visual message should be the best fitting with the image on the paper shown above. Thank you so much

Something like this?
I used center environment (with \captionof) to avoid floating.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}
\definecolor{rowcol}{rgb}{0.7, 0.7, 0.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[c,m,wd=3cm]Q[c,m] *{4}{Q[.7cm,c,m]}},
    cells={font=\large},
    row{Y-Z}={bg=rowcol},
    hline{2,X-Z}={1-Z}{leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
    hline{3-W}={3-Z}{leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
    vline{3,Z}={1-Z}{solid},
    vline{1,2,4-Y}={2-Z}{solid},
    rowsep=6pt,
    }
    & Countries & 1 & 2 & $\ldots$ & N \\
    \SetCell[r=4]{c,m}Inputs &1& $Z_{11}$ & $Z_{12}$ & $\ldots$ & $Z_{1N}$ \\
    &2& $Z_{21}$ & $Z_{22}$ & $\ldots$ & $Z_{2N}$ \\
    & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
    &$N$& $Z_{N1}$ & $Z_{N2}$ & $\ldots$ & $Z_{NN}$ \\
    \SetCell[c=2]{l}Value Added && VA$_1$ & VA$_2$ & $\ldots$ & VA$_4$ \\
    \SetCell[c=2]{l}Total Output && $X_1$ & $X_2$ & $\ldots$ & $X_4$ \\
  \end{tblr}
  \captionof{table}{Caption}
\end{center}
\end{document}



Thank you. However, It's not working. It gives me an error. It says missing number treated as zero

@Maximilian Is your TeX Live distribution up to date?

I've just updated the packages through the MikTex console. However, TexStudio tells me "No file texstudio_yZKKVc.aux."

@Maximilian Recompile from scratch (deleting the previous auxiliary files).

Still, it does not work: "Missing number, treated as zero. \end"

@Maximilian I tried on Overleaf and it works: https://www.overleaf.com/read/npmktcxtvqkc#af00af I think you don't have an up-to-date distribution.

Ok, I'll try again to update the Live distribution

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{2cm}cccw{c}{1cm}c}[hvlines,corners]
                    & countries & 1 & 2 & $\cdots$ & $N$ \\
\Block{4-1}{Inputs} & $1$ & $Z_{11}$ & $Z_{12}$ & $\cdots$ & $Z_{1N}$ \\
                    & $2$ & $Z_{21}$ & $Z_{22}$ & $\cdots$ & $Z_{2N}$ \\
                    \\[1cm]
%                    & $\vdots$  & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$   &  & $\vdots$ \\
                    & $N$ & $Z_{N1}$ & $Z_{N2}$ & $\cdots$ & $Z_{NN}$ \\
\Block[l]{1-2}{Value Added} & & VA$_1$ & VA$_2$ & $\cdots$ & VA$_4$ \\
\Block[l]{1-2}{Total output} & & $X_1$ & $X_2$  & $\cdots$ & $X_4$ \\
\CodeAfter
  \line[shorten=12pt]{3-2}{5-2}
  \line[shorten=12pt]{3-3}{5-3}
  \line[shorten=12pt]{3-4}{5-4}
  \line[shorten=12pt]{3-6}{5-6}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}

You need several compilations (because nicematrix uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

